# IConfiguration with IOptions - How to reload configuration from external source in every request scope

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration

**Goal**

I would like to develop an application that fetches its configurations in real-time from an external web service based on a runtime value (tenantId). This means that for each request/scope, the configurations should be reloaded. As a first step, configuration caching is not required

**Approach / Thoughts / Questions**

1. Since dotnet core provides the `IConfiguration` interface that works well with the Options Pattern I was wondering if the above is achievable through a custom `ConfigurationProvider` that deals with a per-request configuration load while the rest of the application injects `IOptionsSnapshot<>` to fetch the configuration.

   - My initial thought was to use a middleware that triggers a reload in every request but this seems a bit of a hack and probably not the best approach?
2. For my requirements, would it be better to just use the Options pattern with a custom `IConfigureOptions` implementation for each option that would fetch the config in runtime instead of using a custom `ConfigurationProvider`?

   - In this case, how can I overcome scenarios in which external class libraries request an IConfigurationSection to fetch their configuration?
3. Is it better to avoid any of the above approaches and just use a custom service that would be injected by any service that requires a configuration value?

   - This would allow more control in handling the configuration and the cache , but it means that this custom configuration service would be propagated within the whole application instead of using the standard IConfiguration. This could be ok I guess, but again we have to deal with external libraries that use IConfiguration.
4. Is there another recommended approach that I have not listed and you consider a better option for my requirements?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following a hybrid approach in which I don't use a `ConfigurationProvider` but still use the `IConfiguration` interface to work with configurations. The approach I followed is:

1. The `IConfiguration` interface is still used for configuring the different configuration providers
2. `IOptionsSnapshot<ConfigClassOptions>` is injected in all parts of the application that need configuration values
3. A middleware executed just after the authorization middleware, reads the runtime value from the header of the request, then fetches the corresponding configurations based on the runtime value and overrides the configurations by adding the corresponding key values directly on `IConfiguration` instance. `IConfiguration[key]=value;`